# What changes and updates are needed for FCM based push notification from MobileFirst App Center 7.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, push

I understand that there's guide documentation updates on how to configure and send FCM based push notification for Android app via Console in MobileFirst Foundation v8, but I'm wondering how App Center, which is based on v7.1, service side configuration and mobile client updates should be done to send push notification via FCM for app updates.

What changes do I need to make for FCM push notification in App Center server configuration?

What changes do I need to make for FCM push notification handling in App Center mobile client - e.g. changing/updating SDKs/libraries included in v7.1 based client package?

Comment: When you ask for changes you need to make, you should probably provide what code you have so far...

Answer (score 3):

Ideally giving the FCM Credentials instead of GCM credentials and with/without the endpoint changes and it should work.

Changes:

a) ibm.appcenter.gcm.signature.googleapikey = (Firebase Cloud Messaging token in server.xml at server side)

b) gcmProjectId = (FCM sender in config.json at client side)

**For reference:**

[Configuring AppCenter Push](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/push-notifications/)

[Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)

Comment: So the GCM android client did receive the notification via IBM cloud notification service which has FCM configuration, right?